# Codeigniter Datamapper many-to-many relationships

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I’m setting up relationships in my models using DataMapper but I’ve hit a wall.

I have a `RealEstate` class, a `Client` class and a `Position` class which all have many to many relationships.

1. `Client` can have the `Position` ‘buyer’ in a `RealEstate`
2. Same `Client` can have the `Position` ‘seller’ in another `RealEstate`

So for a given `RealEstate` it’s easy to find all the `Clients`s attached to it, but how can I also include what `Position` those clients have for the specific `RealEstate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an incorrect design for it. It really should be many-to-many relationship between `Client` and `Position`, but only one-to-many relationship between `Position` and `RealEstate`, with *one* on `RealEstate` side. It effectively emulates many-to-many relationship between `RealEstate` and `Client` that have an additional info (`Position`) in it.

Speaking in terms of problem domain, any role (`Position`) is *attached* to specific `RealEstate`, but any `Client` can have arbitrary number of roles and any `RealEstate` can(?) have multiple roles attached to it.

I don't have CodeIgniter 2 at fingertips, so can't provide code samples, but let me know if you really need it - I have it CodeIgniter 2 at home.

Comment: So I have a RealEstate class, a Position class and a Client class.
A RealEstate has several Positions attached to it (you can look at these as groups. These Positions contain Clients. For example, in RealEstate APPARTMENT1 the Client John Doe is in the Position as owner. But he can be in another position for another RealEstate!

In my database I have

- RealEstates
- Clients
- Positions
- Clients_Positions (many to many)
- Positions_RealEstates (one to many)

How can I get all the Clients that have a Position at a given RealEstate. Should there also be a Clients_RealEstates table?

Comment: I don't think so. The raw query is something like `select * from clients c join clients_positions cp where cp.estate_id = $estate_id`. I'm not familiar with CI DataMapper lib, so can't help transforming this query into DataMapper code, sorry. :)

Comment: Hi @J0HN, I managed to fix it myself. So I normalized the many to many relationship to a one to many relationship between Client and Contract, Property and Contract and Position and Contract. The Contract table and model has the id/foreignkeys of all other objects and knows which one are connected. Thanks for your input!